# Mysql, 3 tables 2 group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables, student, family and fee. Some families have more than one kid. Fees are recorded in fee table. Families makes many payments through the year.
I want to group the number of kids by family and get the total amount paid by each family.
My Qyery:

```
SELECT student.Family_ID, family.Family_Name, count(*) as kids_numb, sum (Amount)  as Paid_Amount        
      FROM student, family, fee 
      WHERE student.Family_ID = family.Family_ID
      AND fee.Family_ID = family.Family_ID
      AND student.Status ='1'
      GROUP BY student.Family_ID;
```

I need to sort Something like:

```
Family Name  |  # of kids |  Fees  | Paid  | Balance
----------------------------------------------------
Lebon        |      1     |  425   | 200   |  225
Lavoix       |      2     |  700   | 150   |  550
Napper       |      1     |  425   |  0    |  425
Major        |      3     |  900   | 300   |  600
```

Comment: Please show exact table schemas (e.g. as a result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`). Does `amount` belong to `fee` table? Where total `fees` value should be coming from?

Comment: Yes amount belongs to fee table.

Comment: Only one thing, if status =0 for all kids of family the query still return a row. In the demo suppose that family_id (3) has both kids left school (status=0), then the query return a row with NULL as # of kids. Thanks

Comment: Wonderful! it worked. You are so good man. Thank you from my heart

Comment: sorry to come back again here. I am wondering if it is possible to add a 'WITH ROLLUP' to calculate the total amount. Thank you

Comment: The grand total was shown only with: GROUP BY family_id WITH ROLLUP, it doesn't show with the other code. But until here I am good I can manage it. Thank you again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on your comments.

Try it this way

```
SELECT m.family_id, m.family_name, s.kids_numb, COALESCE(f.paid_amount, 0) paid_amount
  FROM family m LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT family_id, COUNT(*) kids_numb
    FROM student
   WHERE status = 1
   GROUP BY family_id
 ) s 
    ON m.family_id = s.family_id LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT family_id, SUM(amount) paid_amount
    FROM fee 
    GROUP BY family_id
) f
  ON m.family_id = f.family_id
 WHERE s.family_id IS NOT NULL
```

Sample output:

```
| FAMILY_ID | FAMILY_NAME | KIDS_NUMB | PAID_AMOUNT |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|         1 |       Lebon |         1 |         200 |
|         2 |      Lavoix |         2 |         150 |
|         3 |      Napper |         1 |           0 |
|         4 |       Major |         3 |         300 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e898/2)** demo

---

**UPDATE2:** to add a grand total

```
SELECT family_id, family_name, SUM(kids_numb) kids_numb, SUM(paid_amount) paid_amount
  FROM
(
  SELECT m.family_id, m.family_name, s.kids_numb, COALESCE(f.paid_amount, 0) paid_amount
    FROM family m LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT family_id, COUNT(*) kids_numb
      FROM student
     WHERE status = 1
     GROUP BY family_id
   ) s 
      ON m.family_id = s.family_id LEFT JOIN 
  (
    SELECT family_id, SUM(amount) paid_amount
      FROM fee 
      GROUP BY family_id
  ) f
    ON m.family_id = f.family_id
   WHERE s.family_id IS NOT NULL
) q
 GROUP BY family_id, family_name WITH ROLLUP
HAVING (family_id IS NOT NULL AND 
        family_name IS NOT NULL)
    OR (family_id IS NULL AND 
        family_name IS  NULL)
```

Sample output:

```
| FAMILY_ID | FAMILY_NAME | KIDS_NUMB | PAID_AMOUNT |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|         1 |       Lebon |         1 |         200 |
|         2 |      Lavoix |         2 |         150 |
|         3 |      Napper |         1 |           0 |
|         4 |       Major |         3 |         300 |
|    (null) |      (null) |         7 |         650 |
```

MySQL `GROUP BY` non-standard extension will allow you to change this whole part

```
 GROUP BY family_id, family_name WITH ROLLUP
HAVING (family_id IS NOT NULL AND 
        family_name IS NOT NULL)
    OR (family_id IS NULL AND 
        family_name IS  NULL)
```

with just

```
 GROUP BY family_id WITH ROLLUP
```

but then instead of `NULL` in `family_name` column for a total row you'll have a value of last family name.

Sample output:

```
| FAMILY_ID | FAMILY_NAME | KIDS_NUMB | PAID_AMOUNT |
|-----------|-------------|-----------|-------------|
|         1 |       Lebon |         1 |         200 |
|         2 |      Lavoix |         2 |         150 |
|         3 |      Napper |         1 |           0 |
|         4 |       Major |         3 |         300 |
|    (null) |       Major |         7 |         650 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e898/14)** demo

Comment: See updated answer. BTW you better write comments to the answer rather than to your question.

Comment: If it's not working then you most likely copied it wrong. Did you take a look at working sqlfiddle example I provided? And again please leave comments to **my** answer not to **your** own question.

Comment: Sorry for the comments. Yes I always check your examples first. I am testing in my local machine. I even made a copy/paste from your query and still only the small code works for me. Maybe something in my PHP code? I will find it. but believe me I am fine with what I have. Thanks a lot